# AWS-Lambda 302 Not Redirecting after getting response from Axios (Frontend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to setup a Google-OAuth flow using serverless and AWS-Lambdas. To start, I have a button that kicks off the process by hitting a lambda endpoint. However, the page never actually redirects to the authentication page. Instead I get an error on the FE:

```
Request failed with status code 302
```

Frontend logic:

```
const redirectToGoogleOAuth = async (user) => {
  try {
    const endpoint = process.env.GOOGLE_PATH_ENDPOINT;

    const response = await axios.get(endpoint, {
      responseType: 'text',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user}`,
      },
    });

    // Expect redirect at this point

    return response.data.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Lambda Endpoint:

```
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
  const responseType = 'code'
  const googleAuthorizeURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth'
  const scope = 'openid email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
  const accessType = 'offline'

  try {
    const params = [
      `response_type=${responseType}`,
      `client_id=${googleClientId}`,
      `redirect_uri=${baseURL}`,
      `scope=${scope}`,
      `state="state"`,
      `access_type=${accessType}`
    ]

    const googleOAuthEndPath = `${googleAuthorizeURL}?${params.join('&')}`
    const response = {
      statusCode: 302,
      body: '',
      headers: {
        location: googleOAuthEndPath
      }
    }

    return response
  } catch (err) {
    return response(400, err.message)
  }
}
```

In the lambda-response, I've added a header for location with the google-path. However, the frontend does not seem to consume the response correctly. The frontend interprets the 302 as in error instead of redirecting to the specific page. Any ideas on how I may resolve this so it actually redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Axios uses [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), which [always follows redirects by itself and therefore Axios can't do anything about it](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932#issuecomment-307390761) (unless you rely on hacks, discussed in the same link).

You might have to use something other than Axios for this part, such as the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which [supports manual redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request).

GitHub user [`parties`](https://github.com/parties) suggested [the `fetch()` equivalent](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932#issuecomment-515229573) in the same Axios issue linked above:

```
fetch("/api/user", {
    redirect: "manual"
}).then((res) => {
    if (res.type === "opaqueredirect") {
        window.location.href = res.url;
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}).catch(handleFetchError);
```